# Transition from TFVC Path-Based Branches to Git

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, git-branch, tfvc

We currently have one TFVC Repository with a lot of path-based branches at the folder levels. For example,

```
TFVC_Repo
   Product A (Folder)
      Dev (Branch)
      Main (Branch)
   Product B (Folder)
      Dev (Branch)
      Main (Branch)
```

If we convert this repo into Git and want to maintain a somewhat similar structure, since Git doesn't have folder-level branches, is the only option creating multiple repos for each Product? So, we'll end up with:

```
Git Repo Product A
      Dev (Branch)
      Master (Branch)
Git Repo Product B
      Dev (Branch)
      Master (Branch)
```

Thank you for any guidance you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFVC branch and Git branch, even though the name is similar, but there have been many differences.

> *Are there similarities between TFVC and Git branch strategies?*
>
> The TFVC Feature Isolation branching strategy is similar to the Git
>   [topic branches](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows#Topic-Branches).

You should **select a branching strategy for Git** when you plan your migration to Git.

> If you’re currently using a long-lived feature branch strategy, it may
>   be easiest to begin adopting feature flags before migrating to Git, so
>   that you need to migrate as few branches as possible. Be sure to
>   document the mapping between legacy branches and the new branches in
>   Git so that your team understands where they should commit their new
>   work.

More details please take a look at this tutorial：[Plan your migration to Git](https://www.visualstudio.com/learn/centralized-to-git/)

Besides, it's able to make branches to be created in folders with TFS GIT, please follow: **[Create a new branch from the web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/create-branch#create-a-new-branch-from-the-web)**, just convenient to manage and only available with TFS 2017 above version.

[image]